# Widget OnClickPendingIntent Not Received By Service

Tags: android, service, android-widget, android-pendingintent

Because of limitation of this site, i can't post everything related to my issue.
So you can read the everything where: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/299148-widget-onclickpendingintent-not-received-by-service/

Basically, I've a widget to my music-app that shows the current playing song and should allow the user to toggle play or change track. The widget update nicely, but the Service don't received by the Service.

This is how i set the OnClickPendingIntent:

```
  RemoteViews updateViews = null;
  ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, GMWidget.class);
  updateViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
  Intent WIDGET_PAUSE_PLAY_intent = new Intent(this, GMService.class);
  WIDGET_PAUSE_PLAY_intent.setAction(WIDGET_PAUSE_PLAY);
  PendingIntent WidgetPausePlay = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(WIDGET_PAUSE_PLAY).setComponent(thisWidget), 0);
  updateViews.setonclickPendingIntent(R.id.pbWidMediaPlay, WidgetPausePlay);
```

and this is my OnReceive:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  //  super.onReceive(context, intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG,"CLICKK: " + action);
}
```

and this is my Intent-filter for my Service:

```
<action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" /> />
<action android:name="com.my.player.WIDGET_NEXT" />
<action android:name="com.my.player.WIDGET_PREV" />
<action android:name="com.my.player.WIDGET_PAUSE_PLAY" />
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PendingIntent you created with getService() won't trigger onReceive(). You will need to listen to it in onStartCommand().

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call update. Here is a complete working code from one of my apps. Change it and use it as you see fit.

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider 
{

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
            int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {

        Log.i("Widget", "onUpdate");

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        {

            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Log.i("Widget", "onUpdateLoop");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
            intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetButton, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

  }

}
```

EDIT: Also if you update your widget from anywhere else in the app be sure not to miss any components in the update. Every call to updateAppWidget must have all of the same components in it especially any onPendingIntentClick